# Scala, Docker - how to choose configuration for different environments?

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

I have created a simple application with `DockerPlugin` in `sbt` file and it uses my default `application.conf` file to load resources. But now, I will need to change this configurations depend on environment (other for dev, other one for prod). Is it possible to tell docker which configuration file should be used? I tried to separate `application.conf` data into `prod` and `dev` and load files in case of given environment in path, but I don't think so it is good solution.

Comment: You can also set JVM system properties in your Docker file `-Dconfig.file=somethingElse.conf` or even `-Djust.one.conf.toOverride=foo`. But in general configuring containers via environment variables is the easiest way (and best integrated with deployment tools).

Comment: `But in general configuring containers via environment variables is the easiest way (and best integrated with deployment tools)` - you mean my approach with separating application.conf was good?

Comment: You may not need to separate if you make the relevant pieces overridable by environment variable right in `application.conf`:  `x = true; x = ${?FOO}`.  https://github.com/lightbend/config#optional-system-or-env-variable-overrides

Comment: If you have a lot of those, you can also have the container mount an additional config file (from the host system) and point `-Dconfig.file` at that (and that file can still `include` the normal one and only override what it needs to override).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try first of all use overridable env variables and set them by ansible, it should be enough.